# Using sets with the multiprocessing module

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I can't seem to share a set across processes using a Manager instance.
A condensed version of my code:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
manager = SyncManager()
manager.start()
manager.register(Set)
```

I've also tried `register(type(Set))` and `register(Set())`, but I'm not overly surprised that neither of them worked (the first should evaluate to Class, I think).

The exception I get in all cases is `TypeError: __name__ must be set to a string object` in line 675 of managers.py.

Is there a way of doing this, or do I need to investigate alternatives?

Comment: Why use `Set` (the module) when you have `set` (the built-in type)?

Comment: And the `.register()` method needs more arguments, the first argument being the *name* of the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to the [`SyncManager.register()` class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register) must be a *string*, not a cass:

```
SyncManager.register('set', set)
```

but you'll need to register a proxy for sets as well:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import MakeProxyType

BaseSetProxy = MakeProxyType('BaseSetProxy', (
    '__and__', '__contains__', '__iand__', '__ior__', 
    '__isub__', '__ixor__', '__len__', '__or__', '__rand__', '__ror__', '__rsub__',
    '__rxor__', '__sub__', '__xor__', 'add', 'clear', 'copy', 'difference',
    'difference_update', 'discard', 'intersection', 'intersection_update', 'isdisjoint',
    'issubset', 'issuperset', 'pop', 'remove', 'symmetric_difference', 
    'symmetric_difference_update', 'union', 'update']
    ))
class SetProxy(BaseSetProxy):
    # in-place hooks need to return `self`, specify these manually
    def __iand__(self, value):
        self._callmethod('__iand__', (value,))
        return self
    def __ior__(self, value):
        self._callmethod('__ior__', (value,))
        return self
    def __isub__(self, value):
        self._callmethod('__isub__', (value,))
        return self
    def __ixor__(self, value):
        self._callmethod('__ixor__', (value,))
        return self

SyncManager.register('set', set, SetProxy)
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks for pointing out the stuff I really should have noticed when I RTFM.

Comment: @Hotchips: I am re-introducing the `__i*__` names to the `exposed` list for the proxy; reading the `ListProxy` code I think I may have discovered a bug in that it doesn't expose the `list.__iadd__` method properly. Not 100%, but listing them in the `BaseSetProxy` list does no harm, and omitting them could be a bug.